# Can we use sendKeys(Keys.RETURN) ,sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) and sendKeys(Keys.SPACE) to click button or select checkbox

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to know if we can use `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)` , `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` and `sendKeys(Keys.SPACE)` to click a button or to select a checkbox.

When I am using `click();` nothing is happening (neither clicking on the box nor closing the browser).
When am using `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` the browser is closing without selecting box

HTML:

```
<section class="payment-buttons">
    <div class="section-heading">
        <h2>  How would you like to pay?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-type-selection clearfix">
        <div class="payment-type creditdebit-btn" data-source="creditdebit" onclick="creditdebitSelect(this,'true');">
            <h5>Credit or Debit Card</h5>
            <i class="icon-cards"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="payment-type paypal-btn" data-source="paypal" onclick="paypalSelect(this,'true');">
            <h5>PayPal</h5>
            <i class="icon-paypal"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="payment-type giftcard-btn" data-source="giftcard" onclick="giftcardSelect(this,'true');">
            <h5>Gift Card</h5>
            <i class="icon-giftcard"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Code:

```
WebDriverWait wait1=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/section/div[2]/div"))).click();
```

Can anyone please tell me how to click on the button for above code?

Comment: What `creditdebitSelect(this,'true')` does? Are you trying to click on something (div with an icon) to check another component (another input checkbox)? Can you try to change your `By.xpath(...)` for `By.cssSelector("div[data-source='creditdebit'] i.icon-cards")` to see if it works?

Comment: still same thing happening..browser closing without clicking on icon.by clicking on this icon/box this creditdebitSelect(this,'true'); function will call and open card details form.

Comment: i got below error when using with css locator
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element <i class="icon-cards"></i> is not clickable at point (273, 567.7999877929688). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader-overlay" style="opacity: 0.143681;"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 73 milliseconds

Comment: This error shows that the element can be: 1) not in your view port; 2) overlapped by some other element. According to the coordinates in the exception, it seems another element is overlapping this icon. Can you inspect with dev tools to see if there isn't anything else in another layer, above the icon?

Comment: updated the source code

Answer (score 0):

You can force click element like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait1=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(wait1.until(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='category']/option[@id='cat2']"))).click().build().perform();
```

Hope it helps you :)